# How to get all pixel positions between two non linear points opencv

Tags: opencv, line, coordinates, pixel

How to get all pixel positions(coordinates) along a line between two non linear points P1 and P2?
My actualwork is to change the value of  a pixel located in between P1 and P2 which is at a particular distance from P1, for this i need to know all the pixel coordinates.
 With the `LineIterator` i am able to access all the pixel values. But I don't know how to get the pixel coordinates.
Can anyone suggest me how to get the coordinates??

Answer (score 0):

`cv::LineIterator` class is [documented](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/dd2/classcv_1_1LineIterator.html#ac83a4c574ce6a50a78a52d7eee10371b) well.

The method `LineIterator::pos` returns the current position in the image.

take a look at this sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    Mat img(400,400,CV_8UC3,Scalar(0,0,0));

    LineIterator it(img, Point(10,10), Point(200,200), 8);

    for(int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, ++it)
    {
        Point pt= it.pos();
        circle(img,pt,2,Scalar(255,0,0));
    }
    imshow("test",img);
    waitKey();
}
```