# How do I use OpenCV to detect exclusively almost straight edges?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I'm trying to detect straight edges in a basketball card and what I have so far does a good job of detecting all edges. I would like for this piece of code however, to detect exclusively straight edges (the outline of the card).

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

img = cv2.imread('edgedetection/cardgiannis.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel_size = 5
blur_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(kernel_size, kernel_size),0)

low_threshold = 50
high_threshold = 150
edges = cv2.Canny(blur_gray, low_threshold, high_threshold)

rho = 1  # distance resolution in pixels of the Hough grid
theta = np.pi / 180  # angular resolution in radians of the Hough grid
threshold = 15  # minimum number of votes (intersections in Hough grid cell)
min_line_length = 50  # minimum number of pixels making up a line
max_line_gap = 20  # maximum gap in pixels between connectable line segments
line_image = np.copy(img) * 0  # creating a blank to draw lines on

# Run Hough on edge detected image
# Output "lines" is an array containing endpoints of detected line segments
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]),
                    min_line_length, max_line_gap)

for line in lines:
    for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
        cv2.line(line_image,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,0,0),5)

# Draw the lines on the  image
lines_edges = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.8, line_image, 1, 0)
cv2.imshow('lines', lines_edges)
cv2.waitKey()
```

[image: Basketball Card with edged highlighted]

Comment: Detecting almost straight lines and detecting the outlie of the card are two very different problems. IMO, you should change the title.

Comment: As usual, edge detection believed to be the panacea, when detection of the white borders would be much easier...

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think.

If you can somehow get the highest & lowest valued coordinates in the pixels that are forming the lines, you can use those pixels to form a rectangle that consist of the straight edges.

[image]

Using the pixels to (roughly) form a rectangle can be the solution!

---

To find the pixels in a line, you can take a look in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36774004/how-to-get-all-pixel-positions-between-two-non-linear-points-opencv), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69233701/finding-the-coordinates-of-pixels-over-a-line-in-an-image) and [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71271409/find-pixels-that-line-passes-over)

Comment: I may be wrong but I guess that OP wants the outline of the card.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. I was so excited about my idea for some reason. :) In that case, we need to find the **second highest/lowest** coordinates for the edges around the card, if we are using pixels again.

Comment: Second highest (whatever that means) does not work.

Comment: Okay @YvesDaoust :)

Comment: As I said in another comment, for this case using edge detection alone is the best way to disaster.

Comment: Thank you for clarification on how to solve this problem, I'm obviously novice on the matter. Grateful for your point of view.

Answer (score 0):

you may use cv.approxPolyDP to extract dominant points from edges and stick to the edges that have 2 dominant points.

ps: you apply approxPolyDP on edges after collecting them by cv.findcontours